# Автоматическое увеличение цифры раз в день

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как "меньшей кровью" сделать автоматическое прибавление цифр раз в сутки на сайте? Т.е., например, есть блок "готовые работы", и их там 100, заходим завтра, а их уже 102.

Comment: Запомни дату запуска программы в ини или файл, вычитай из текущей даты и получишь разницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(floor( time() / 86400) - 16375) * 2 + 100;
```

Начиная с сегодняшнего дня будет увеличиваться со 100 с шагом 2.

- [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) – число секунд с 1 января 1970 года (по Гринвичу);
- 86400 – число секунд в сутках (`60*60*24`);
- 16375 дней прошло на сегодня с 1-го января 1970;